# Unir varios registros repetidos sumando puntajes por trimestre

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenos dias tengo la siguiente consulta:
[image: tabla]

Utilice la siguiente consulta para unir los registros, pero no logro conseguir la consulta

```
SELECT DISTINCT aPaterno,aMaterno,Nombres, SUM(eval1+eval2+eval3+eval4) as total FROM `notas` WHERE 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es el resultado final que necesito realizar.

Comment: La estructura de tabla es redundate e ineficiente, por lo que esa consulta será complicada. Los estudiantes no tienen un id único, ¿los estudiantes solo cursan 1 año?. Necesitas al menos 3 tablas: Una para **estudiantes** (con un id único por estudiante), otra para **trimestre** (con su repectivo año) y otra para las **notas**. Aprende sobre [normalización de datos](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+normalizaci%C3%B3n). Puedes guiarte de [ejemplos](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+estudiantes+notas) en internet de estos casos.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas agregar un condicional para que solo te agregue el trimestre que quieres en cada columna.

```
SELECT aPaterno,
       aMaterno,
       Nombres, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN trimestre = "1TRIMESTRE" THEN eval1+eval2+eval3+eval4 END) as `1TRIMESTRE`, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN trimestre = "2TRIMESTRE" THEN eval1+eval2+eval3+eval4 END) as `2TRIMESTRE`, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN trimestre = "3TRIMESTRE" THEN eval1+eval2+eval3+eval4 END) as `3TRIMESTRE`, 
       SUM( eval1+eval2+eval3+eval4) as total 
FROM `notas` 
GROUP BY aPaterno,
         aMaterno,
         Nombres
```